# How to validate route parameter in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, nuxt.js

I am trying to validate route parameter in my page component like this:

```
async validate({ params, store }) {
    await store.dispatch(types.VALIDATE_PARAMS_ASYNC, params.id)
}
```

Then in store:

```
async [types.VALIDATE_PARAMS_ASYNC]({state, commit, dispatch}, payload) {
    try {
        const res = await this.$axios.$post('/api/params/validate', {
            params: payload
        })
        commit(types.MUTATE_SET_INFO, res.data) // this mutation is in another module. This doesn't work either
        return true
    } catch(e) {
        return false
    }
}
```

This doesn't work at all. Even if I type invalid params, it still loads the page. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `validate` method must return a boolean:

```
async validate({ params, store}) {
    // await operations
   return true // if the params are valid
   return false // will stop Nuxt.js to render the route and display the error page
}
```

see official documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-validate#the-validate-method

---

```
async validate({ params, store }) {
    return await store.dispatch(types.VALIDATE_PARAMS_ASYNC, params.id)
}
```

Comment: I am returning the boolean!

Comment: not here : async validate({ params, store }) {
    await store.dispatch(types.VALIDATE_PARAMS_ASYNC, params.id)
}